# Immediately invoked function expressions runs the last defined function. Why?

Tags: javascript, iife

I came across some strange behavior that I didn't expect to happen when using an immediately invoked function expression. The below code runs the function `hello` when there is an IIFE at the end. Why is this happening?

```
var hello = function () {
    console.log("hello");
}

(function () {

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this, it won't

```
var hello = function () {
    console.log("hello");
};

(function () {
})();
```

Its because the JavaScript interpreter understands it as continuous code unless you put the `;` to mark it as end of your statement.

Your code

```
var hello = function () {
    console.log("hello");
}

(function () {
})();
```

Actually becomes like this

```
var hello = function () {
               console.log("hello");
            }(function(){})();
```

And the interpreter runs the `hello` function immediately by taking `function () {}` as an argument and throws the error for next `()`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Because of semicolon.

JS parser treats your two functions as single one, like this:

`var hello = function () {console.log("hello");}(function () {})();`

So it just runs you 'hello' function because it sees no semicolon between hello and IIFE

Comment: @AlexanderT correct thanks.. was adding that in description

Comment: @AlexanderT: FWIW, I know why, but an answer should **explain** the solution, not just contain code.Your explanation should be part of the answer.

Comment: @FelixKling sure, I added some explanation :)

Comment: It's not the end of the block. It's the end of a statement.

Comment: @torazaburo for statements Interpreter understands end as new line

Comment: I am pointing out the difference between "statement" and "block", which are different terms meaning different things, and you are using the term "block" incorrectly in your answer. Blocks are things in curly brackets. It is also not correct to say that *for statements interpreter understands end as newline"; `return` is a notable exception.

Comment: I think its correct, I am referring to the `var hello = function(){}` block only, for statements new line is end but not for block right?

Comment: @vinayakj: No. That is not a block. That is a *variable declaration statement*. And it doesn't end at the new line, otherwise `var hello = <new line here> function(){}` wouldn't work.

Comment: From Wikipedia: _In computer programming, a block or code block is a section of code which is grouped together. Blocks consist of one or more declarations and statements._

Comment: @torazaburo If you think the description is confusing please go ahead and edit acccordingly..